# Laravel vue 3 issue in JS load

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have facing an problem when i load them home page which is home component then js works fine but when i go to another component then click on home component then js not works fine
here it is my code
this is welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kabira</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Morden Bootstrap HTML5 Template">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="{{asset('newtheme/image/x-icon')}}" href="{{asset('newtheme/assets/img/favicon.ico')}}">
    
   <!-- ======= All CSS Plugins here ======== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('newtheme/assets/css/plugins/swiper-bundle.min.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('newtheme/assets/css/plugins/glightbox.min.css')}}">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&amp;family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Plugin css -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  
  <!-- Custom Style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('newtheme/assets/css/style.css')}}">

  @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>




    @vite('resources/js/app.js')

    <!-- All Script JS Plugins here  -->
  <!-- <script src="assets/js/vendor/popper.js" defer="defer"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js" defer="defer"></script> -->

  <script src="{{asset('newtheme/assets/js/plugins/swiper-bundle.min.js')}}" defer="defer"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('newtheme/assets/js/plugins/glightbox.min.js')}}" defer="defer"></script>

  <!-- Customscript js -->
  <script src="{{asset('newtheme/assets/js/script.js')}}" defer="defer"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

this is app.js here i also import assets

```
import './bootstrap';


import {createApp} from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './routes.js';
import './assets/css/style.css';
import './assets/css/plugins/swiper-bundle.min.css';
import './assets/img/favicon.ico';
import './assets/css/plugins/glightbox.min.css';
import './assets/js/plugins/swiper-bundle.min.js';
import './assets/js/plugins/glightbox.min.js';



createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app")
```

this image when i load the page
[image: when load page and js works]

this comes when i come on home component from other component
[image: when comes from other component]

here it is my routes.js code

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory}  from 'vue-router';
import homepagecomponent from './home/homeone.vue';
import aboutuscomponent from './pages/aboutUs.vue';
import contactuscomponent from './pages/contactUs.vue';
import shopgridcomponent from './shop/shopGrid.vue';

const routes = [

    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home",
        component : homepagecomponent,
    },
    {
        path : "/about-us",
        name : "about_us",
        component : aboutuscomponent,
    },
    {
        path : "/contact-us",
        name : "contact_us",
        component : contactuscomponent,
    },
    {
        path : "/shop",
        name : "shop",
        component : shopgridcomponent,
    }

];

const router = createRouter({
    history:createWebHistory(),
    routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: What router are you using, Laravel's or Vue.js's? It appears that you're using Vue.js's, but if you are creating a Laravel-Vue-Inertia app, shouldn't it in fact be Laravel's router?

Comment: If you are using Inertia, such as via Laraval's Breeze or JetStream starter kits, then this information from the [Inertia site](https://inertiajs.com/routing) is relevant: "*When using Inertia, all of your application's routes are defined server-side. This means that you don't need Vue Router or React Router. Instead, you can simply define Laravel routes and return Inertia responses from those routes.*"

Comment: But also, regardless of which router you use, your routing is likely related to your problem, and you may want to post more information about this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for comment.... i am using laravel vue 3 only..  i didnot use inertia...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i am using vue router 4... add routes.js code now you can check

Comment: if i add this line in app.js  import './assets/js/script.js';  then face error in console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:1:2239